# AC/DC converter followed by DC/DC converters

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I really like experimenting with DC power converter designs and want to build some lab bench power supplies for fun. I do not have interest in dealing with AC power.

I’d like to buy an off the shelf AC/DC converter and then follow it with my own DC/DC converter design. How standard practice is this?

It’s not really clear to me if AC/DC converters generally already include a DC/DC regulator on the output. Cascading two DC/DC converters seems like such a waste, from an efficiency perspective.

Comment: *It’s not really clear to me if AC/DC converters generally already include a DC/DC regulator* - there is no "generally" here. Some do, some do not.

Comment: If we assume most wall warts, power bricks and psu modules are of the switchmode variety, then, yes, they will most likely have some form of regulation in them. Internally they have a rectifier to convert ac to dc then use some form of switching dc/dc converter. As for having two psus, yes, that is very common. Just look in your average PC - big box for the ac to dc then a variety of dc/dc converters for the cpu and graphics chip etc. Commonly known as POL - point of load. Your cpu might want 1V at 70A - you really don’t want to run very thick wires any distance.

Comment: As Andy suggests, reverse engineer a commercial psu. There should be no shortage of candidates. After a while you should be able to identify the topology - buck, boost, flyback etc are common. There’s also extensive resources on the interwebs.

Comment: Before you go trying to reverse engineer anything, if you're a hobbyist with an interest but not a full education in EE like myself, try to build something simpler first!  You can buy a crappy(not lab grade) benchtop power supply kit very cheaply to give more options than a PC PSU gives you just FYI.  Once you've obtained a reasonable and safe DC input voltage(Don't go higher than 50V), instead of trying to build a voltage and current regulated variable benchtop power supply, build a buck regulator.  Then a boost regulator, then a buck/boost, a cuk or whatever other you want to try.

Comment: Once you can build the basic duty cycle controlled version of each topology, try a voltage regulator and a current regulator version or one with voltage controlled variable output.  Once you get that far, building a benchtop supply is just a matter of figuring out the control circuit, which if you want you could do with an Arduino or whatever microcontroller and produce a very intelligent power supply.  There are also some old benchtop power supply designs that are extremely well and publicly documented and you can buy assembly kits to match the design on Aliexpress.

Comment: I'd link you to the kits and documents, except it was my father who actually located that particular pairup.  The operational descriptions were good enough I could understand how it worked, despite being complex.  The power supply was OK, but because the design was so old, even after we upgraded all the OP-amps with superior drop in replacements, it was prone to blowing a fuse or burning out an op amp and it didn't have great load regulation.

Comment: I replaced it with a newer digital kit(~$20) that I don't understand how works but has a screen and 3 knob/buttons.  Have to supply your own transformer(scavenged/free), sheet metal box($3 if you have tools) and optional fan(digital supply doesn't get very hot so I haven't added one).  It has voltage and current limiting and readout and 1 isolated DC channel.  The load regulation is way better than with the older design, but probably not nearly as good as a modern lab grade one.

Comment: That gave me ~26V@2A in a convenient format to let me get started on building the converter topologies 1 by 1.  I haven't learned to program a microcontroller yet, but I'm pretty good at logic(I find analog much more challenging), so instead of using all in one chips I built each topology at ~50-100kHz(Baby frequencies) with logic gates, comparators and 555 timer chips.  Inductor selection was the biggest challenge I found.  After doing all that, building a regulator from a dedicated chip with all the helpful documents provided these days isn't too hard.

Comment: I guess I should have been clearer that I am actually educated and employed as an electrical engineer. I’m just interested in learning more about my options to play with power system topologies and ideas without having to risk my life working with mains power.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering a great design is far better than trying just to use formulae. Try an old PC PSU with a 5V preload.

You need both skills, but measuring every signal to small  & large step-loads and with flyback, is the best way to compare.      - use a 50 Ohm AC coupled load from coax to attenuate probe noise is the best way and use a CPU heatsink with fan and a 100W controllable FET for current steps is a good start for an active load.

Examine the RsLC:Rp Bode plot with simulation such as http://www.Falstad.com/afilter and see how removing the load affects. then try to model the slope and phase lead feedback using the ideal Op Amps to quickly model the result. ( some learning curve)

when I used to conduct DVT’s in the 80’s on PSU’s and HDD’s I would use my design skills to reverse engineer each product and compare the timing and window margins for every type of disturbance from heat, shock & vibe  to altitude, crosstalk, EMI susceptibility and much more to understand where the weakness was in each design from Fujitsu, Shindengen, Toshiba, and Seagate, Maxtor,Miniscribe and 20 other competitors.

It’s the best way to learn from others great designs and mistakes.

Comment: I appreciate the response but I actually have no idea what this has to do with my question. I'm trying to understand whether AC/DC converters include a DC/DC regulator already. Is an unregulated AC/DC converter something I can buy?